# Sympy: only enforce constraints where variables are assigned

Tags: python, constraints, sympy, symbols

I'd like to know if there is a way to only enforce constraints where variables are assigned values in Sympy. For example:

```
z=symbols("z:5")
C=[constraint("c1", Ne(z[0],1)), constraint("c2",Ne(z[1],2))]
print([(C[i].subs({z[0]:3})==True) for i in range(2)])
```

output:

```
[True,False]
```

However, as you can see the second constraint is enforced even though z[1] was never substituted a value. I would like for the second constraint to return True since it was never assigned a value. Thanks for your help

-RIk

Comment: I'm not quite clear how you are defining `constraint`, but if `z[1]` is never defined, shouldn't `Ne(z[1], 2)` remain unevaluated and not be True or False, since you don't know if `z[1]` is 2 or not?

Comment: Constraint is defined by Sympy

Comment: I don't see any functions or objects called `constraint` anywhere in SymPy.